# Accessing nested movieclips from main movieclip class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, movieclip

hi
I have a MovieClip, that I'm going to add to the display list with my document class at runtime beacuase there will be many instances of it. The MoviClip "box" has 3 more MovieClip instances inside it, and each of those three have two more. It looks like this:

```
box
    circle 0
        oval0
        oval1
    circle 1
        oval0
        oval1

    circle 2
        oval0
        oval1
```

Here is the code I have right now:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class BoxSet extends MovieClip
    {
        private var theArr:Array;
        public function BoxSet()
        {
            run();
        }
        private function run():void
        {
            theArr = new Array();
            for (var i:uint = 0; i<this.numChildren; i++)
            {
                var mc:MovieClip = this["n" + i] as MovieClip;
                addChild(mc);
                theArr[i] = mc;
                mc.alpha = 0;
            }
        }
        public function setAlpha(num:uint):void
        {
            theArr[num].alpha = 1;
        }
    }

}
```

It's working but I want to know if there is a more efficient way of doing this, or if what I have is a good way of doing it? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have looks perfectly efficient as long as you just want to reference the MovieClip instances by number and not by name.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways for working with nested mcs in as3.0

1.absolute referencing (Rigid) 2. Relative referencing(Flexible).  
In the structure, of nested mcs like mc3-> nested in mc2->nested in mc1 
absolute refrcing will look like e.g. root.mc1.mc2.mc3 to access mc3 frm the main timeline

Relative referencing - at any stage you can refere to the parent of the mc using 
this.parent
 or any other mcs by extentending the abv structure.

sry 4 typos i m in a bit hurry